# Using Crystal reports with Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, crystal-reports

I am using Silverlight to design my web application and want to server up PDF reports to customers. Currently i am using a indirect way of creating the reports by opening a ASPX page in a popup, the popup contains the Crystal Reports viewer that generates the report in a PDF that is then displayed to the client. I want to invoke the crystal reports file from within  my Silverlight application. Is this possible ? If so how can i do this ?

Kind Regards,

Comment: If you are looking for a complete silverlight solution try http://www.stimulsoft.com/ReportsSilverlight.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight does not have a report viewer control for Crystal reports. However, there are two options:

1. Launch another browser window from Silverlight and open the report in new ASPX page (what you did), or
2. Embed a new web page that hosts report viewer control inside the web page that hosts Silverlight application.